# Why does the debian security kernel have a lower version than the main one?

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, security

I just updated my Jessie installation to Stretch.

However I am a lost with Debian kernel versions.

According to [the security tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/linux), the main repository version is **4.9.210-1** but the security version is **4.9.189-3+deb9u2**.

Why is the security version lower?
Which one should I use?

I noticed that [the LTS version](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) is also **4.9.210-1**, I guess because LTS support has not started for Stretch and

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

points to the same version as the one in the main repository.
Can someone please confirm or infirm this guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use whichever version is greater (and `apt` and co. will do the right thing for you), 4.9.210-1 in this case.

The reason this situation arises is that, when a point-release is being prepared, kernel updates will often go straight to stable, without going through security first. A reminder [about the upcoming 9.12 release](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2020/01/msg00122.html) was sent on January 12, 2020, and the kernel [was uploaded on January 20](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1096736/accepted-linux-49210-1-all-source-into-oldstable-proposed-updates-oldstable-new-oldstable-proposed-updates/), in time to get into the point-release (for which updates were frozen on February 1, 2020, two weeks later).

Currently, the kernel packages in all supported releases are in this situation:

- Debian 9 has 4.9.210 in its main repository, 4.9.189 in its security repository;
- Debian 10 has 4.19.98 in its main repository, 4.19.67 in its security repository.

Of course important security issues in the kernel are still fixed through the security repository. (All kernel upgrades fix security issues; not all those fixes are vital.) But the supported distribution is the combination of the main repository and the security repository, not the main repository updated by the security repository.

LTS support for Stretch will only start once security support is no longer available from the main Debian project.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough comment !
I was confused because 4.9.210-1 was built on the 20 of January and I couldn't get why there were others CVEs (such as CVE-2020-7053) which came later and were marked as "fixed" for Stretch, until I discovered the comment at the end of the CVE (<https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2020-7053>) :
"Vulnerable code introduced later", therefore no new build was required.
All clear now, thanks again !